# Fastest way to extract and increase latest number from end of string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of strings that have numbers as suffixes. I'm trying to extract the highest number so I can increase it by 1. Here's what I came up with but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this:

```
data = ["object_1", "object_2", "object_3", "object_blah", "object_123asdfd"]
numbers = [int(obj.split("_")[-1]) for obj in data if obj.split("_")[-1].isdigit()] or [0]
print sorted(numbers)[-1] + 1 # Output is 4
```

A few conditions:

- It's very possible that the suffix is not a number at all, and should be skipped.
- If no input is valid, then the output should be 1 (this is why I have `or [0]`)
- No Python 3 solutions, only 2.7.

Maybe some regex magic would be faster to find the highest number to increment on? I don't like the fact that I have to split twice.

**Edit**

I did some benchmarks on the current answers using 100 iterations on data that has 10000 items:

- Alex Noname's method: 1.65s
- Sushanth's method: 1.95s
- Balaji Ambresh method: 2.12s
- My original method: 2.16s

I've accepted an answer for now, but feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `heapq.nlargest` is a pretty efficient way. Maybe someone will compare with other methods.

```
import heapq

a = heapq.nlargest(1, map(int, filter(lambda b: b.isdigit(), (c.split('_')[-1] for c in data))))[0]
```

Comparing with the original method (Python 3.8)

```
import heapq
import random
from time import time

data = []

for i in range(0, 1000000):
    data.append(f'object_{random.randrange(10000000)}')

begin = time()
a = heapq.nlargest(1, map(int, filter(lambda b: b.isdigit(), (c.split('_')[-1] for c in data))))[0]
print('nlargest method: ', time() - begin)
print(a)

begin = time()
numbers = [int(obj.split("_")[-1]) for obj in data if obj.split("_")[-1].isdigit()] or [0]
a = sorted(numbers)[-1]
print('original method: ', time() - begin)
print(a)
```

```
nlargest method:  0.4306185245513916
9999995
original method:  0.8409149646759033
9999995
```

Comment: You need to add an `int` cast so it can be increased by 1 at the end, but otherwise interesting solution.

Comment: This turned out to be slightly slower than my original answer. Thanks for bringing up `heapq`, I didn't know about it!

Comment: I used `timeit` with a million iterations with this in a function `int(heapq.nlargest(1, map(int, filter(lambda b: b.isdigit(), (c.split('_')[-1] for c in data))))[0]) + 1`

Comment: It definitely scales way better when the list has tons of items. I'll update my timings.

Answer (score 2):

try this, using `list comprehension` to get all digits & `max` would return the highest value.

```
max([
    int(x.split("_")[-1]) if x.split("_")[-1].isdigit() else 0 for x in data
]) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import re
res = max([int( (re.findall('_(\d+)$', item) or [0])[0] ) for item in data]) + 1
```

Value:

```
4
```